# How to rescue Compact Flash card that has been corrupted by a bad formatting

Tags: partitioning, osx-lion, formatting, compact-flash

I used my CompactFlash card as a boot drive to install Snow Leopard for my laptop a while ago. To do that I had to repartition it to HFS+ with a GUID partition table.

When partitioning it back to MBR with FAT32, something failed and now the card is unreadable. When I insert it into the reader it just reads the card and never stops or mounts anything. In Disk Utility it's not appearing either.

Any ideas on how I could possibly rescue the card?

Solutions for Mac OS or Windows are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, did you go to
control panel -> administrative tools -> computer management -> storage -> disk management, and check if it is available there?

One thing you could also try, if you have something like a photocamera which takes CF cards and try to format it with that one.

Comment: Windows Disk Management - Done, reports the card as 6MB instead of 8GB and won't format it. | Camera (Canon 7D) - Formats the card and then tells me the card is corrupt and i should change the card.

Answer (score 0):

I would boot using a version of Ubuntu on a USB drive, then insert your CompactFlash card. Open the disk utilities and go from there. I have used this several times with success.

Comment: I tried this today and the ubuntu disc would only boot until `loading boot image...` then it froze. I'm not really sure if ubuntu would recognize the bluetooth mouse and keyboard either so that's probably a little bit out of scope on the mac.